# WPF project can't load assembly....This assembly is built by a runtime newer

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WPF project.  It's using a library I created with all the business logic and services.  It compiles fine.  The .NET framework (library) targets is .NET 4.  The .NET framework the WPF project targets is .NET 4.

Every dependency that each one of these use is .NET 4.  My only suspicion is with NuGet and the versions of Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor it installs, although in my other WPF projects with NuGet and installing Castle Windsor I haven't had this problem.  I'm lost, no suggestions in the other posts about this same error have resolved the issue.

Any ideas on where else I can look in the project for clues?

Here's the order in what happens when I run the application:

1. first error says: "Error while trying to start the project: Unable to start program 'C:....pathtoBin\DbInstallerWPFForm.exe'"  I then press ok.
2. I then try Debug a second time and the following error comes up (doesn't happen on the first run, only the second):

System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DBInstallerWPFForm.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Can you include the full error message in your question?

Comment: Done, thanks for taking the time to help.